# How to increase quantity in cart Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart

I am doing cart for cafe, everything works fine except increasing quantity. When I add a food to cart...it just dublicating the same food...instead of increase the quantity. I want to make the solution that will check...If the food already in cart...instead of adding it will just increase the quantity. Below is my controller that adds food to cart. Any help will be appreciated

```
def add_to_cart
  add_to_session(params[:cafe], params[:food])
  redirect_to about_cafe_path(Cafe.find(params[:cafe]))
end

def show_cart
  @cart = session[:cart]
end

def clear_cart
  session[:cart] = {}
  redirect_to show_cart_path
end

def remove
  destroy_food(params[:cafe], params[:food])
  redirect_to :back
end

private

def add_to_session(cafe_id, food_id)
  if session[:cart][food_id].present?
    session[:cart][cafe_id][food_id].quantity += 1
  else
    session[:cart][cafe_id].push food_id
  end
end

def destroy_food(cafe_id, food_id)
  session[:cart][cafe_id].delete food_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check `if session[:cart][cafe_id][food_id].present?` instead of `if session[:cart][food_id].present?`

Comment: Anyway doesn't work, it gives error "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: The error you're having now `Anyway doesn't work, it gives error "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"` is because the first time when you add `food_id` to your **session** is with `push`, that means `session[:cart][cafe_id]` is an array, and when you try to increase `quantity`, you're trying to access it as a hash with `session[:cart][cafe_id][food_id]`, that's why you're getting that error. But the reason I didn't write an answer is because `quantity` doesn't exist in the `food_id` Integer you're storing in the Session, for that you need an object with a `quantity` attribute in it.